# How can Python open and play a list of mp3 files with Windows Media Player

Tags: python, list, mp3, windows-media-player

I want to use Python to open and play a list of .mp3 files on Windows Media Player.  I have been able to open a single file with:

```
os.startfile(path_to_file)
```

but I would like to open an entire playlist.  This would be akin to selecting all the files in a folder, right clicking and selecting 'Add to Windows Media Player list'.  I would envision something like:

```
for i in range(NumberOfSongs): 
    os.startfile(Files[i])
```

but this simply cycles through the tracks until the last one and plays that track only.  Does anyone know how to use this function with a list of files or another function that would open media player and add a list of files to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) is going to just open the file with the default associated program, akin to what happens when you double click it.  There is a couple things you can try.

You can try to create a `.m3u` playlist file.  Iterate over the files and programmatically create it.  I recommend looking up the exact details, but they will look something like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:1,Artist - Song title 1
D:\path\to\file\01 Song.mp3
#EXTINF:1,Artist - Song title 2
D:\path\to\file\02 Song.mp3
```

This file also has an associated program, so you can then open it with `os.startfile`.  The number after `EXTINF` is the length of the track in seconds.  It does not appear strictly necessary to have this correct as players I tried would display the correct time.  WMP did not seem to like a value of 0, though, so a value of at least 1 should probably be used.  The path can either be absolute or relative.

There is also [.m3u8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#M3U8) which is the UTF-8 version if you need that.

---

The other option you have is to try to find the command to execute to add to the WMP playlist. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx) appears to be the commands available for WMP.  You maybe want that `/Task NowPlaying` one? They do not have a full example of using it and not clear if you can mix that with opening a file.

Once you know the task and get that working from just the command line, you can try to execute it with something from the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.  Depending on your python version:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

command = 'wmplayer "c:\filename.wma"'
subprocess.run(shlex.split(command), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Don't quote me on those quotes as I do not exactly have the environment to run this, but should be something close to that.  You may or may not want the `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE`.  That will capture the out and err output so you could print them if you wanted but can also be troublesome if the output is large.

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out m3u files are super simple so I just created that and like you said, it opens in WMA and plays all the songs.

Comment: @Casivio Welcome and glad to hear it!